# Inserting model parameters to ext.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ext.net

Is it possible to use model parameters in ext.net?  I am trying to set `ext:label` text attribute to `<%=Html.Encode(Model.Name)%>` but i am getting errors, i also tried using `<%# %>` instead but its not working.

Thanks

Doron

Comment: I think ,maybe will be better to move this question to ASP.NET Forum question or you can ask this question on Ext.NET forum

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
<ext:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"  >
    <Content >
       <%= Html.Encode(Model.Name) %>
    </Content>
 </ext:Label>
```

You can access the label value through **innerHTML** property.

Good luck

ShalomK